# render new state in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to change the state title value to the value I give in the router, but I do not know why it does not work. This code is compiled, but the title is an empty string all the time.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
  };

  updateTitle(title) {
    this.setState({ title });
  }

 render() {
    const { title } = this.state;

    return (
          <Typography>
              {title}
            </Typography>

<Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => (<DashboardPage updateTitle={this.updateTitle} />)}
              title="Dashboard"
            />

            <Route
              path="/payment"
              render={() => (<PaymentPage updateTitle={this.updateTitle} />)}
              title="Payment"
            />

          </Switch>
)};
```

Comment: How are you calling *updateTitle* in the DashboardPage and PaymentPage components?

Comment: Possibly, you need to use an arrow function for `updateTitle` or else it won't have the proper `this` context: `updateTitle = (title) => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the Component method to pass .this context. So `updateTitle = (title)=> {}`

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `this.updateTitle` in an arrow function like below. Then you can call updateTitle from DashBoardPage.

```
<Route
    path="/dashboard"
    render={() => (<DashBoardPage updateTitle={(title) => this.updateTitle(title)} />)}
    title="Dashboard"
/>
```

For example, your DashBoardPage component could look something like below. By calling updateTitle which we have passed as a prop, we are changing the title in the parent component.

**DashBoardPage.js**

```
const DashBoardPage = ({ updateTitle }) => {
    updateTitle('paymentPage');
    return <div>This is the dashboard page</div>;
};
```

However, i would strongly advise against doing this. A better approach would be to have a Page component. Then DashBoardPage and PaymentPage return a Page component and pass the title as prop.

Comment: I do not understand what it means to call updateTitle from DashBoardPage.

Comment: DashBoardPage or PaymentPage are the components that will be rendered. as childs of the Header component. When you pass a function that calls this.updateTitle as a prop to these components (this is what you are doing in your example), then you need to call it in these child components.